# Roll Back Nvidia Driver Without Losing Settings

Tags: windows-7, drivers, nvidia-graphics-card

Basically, I want to roll back my Nvidia driver to an earlier version since the latest version is buggy. However, I have a bunch of custom settings stored in the Nvidia Control Panel and don't want to lose them all  - and I know that if I simply uninstall the old driver and install the new one all the settings will be gone.

Is there a way to install the older driver without losing all my settings?

BTW I'm using Win7x64, Nvidia driver 320.49.

Answer (score -1):

Generally when you have problems with a driver a clean install is the best option. By clean install I mean using `Driver Sweeper` or a similar program to completely wipe the faulty driver(s) and then install another version of that driver.

Obviously in your case this is not a viable option. To keep your settings, all you need to do is download the version of the driver you want and install it using either of the two provided options (`Recommended` or `Custom`). You don't have to do anything special to keep your current `Nvidia Control Panel` settings. The installation wizard even states that the installation will "Retain your current NVIDIA settings."

You could also roll back your settings via the `Device Manager`, but I'm not sure of the effects that option will have on your settings. In my opinion, your best bet is to just install the driver you want via the traditional means.

NOTE: I would use [NVidia inspector](http://downloads.guru3d.com/NVIDIA-Inspector-1.94-download-2612.html) to Export your settings, just in case they are not retained after the driver install. Alternatively, you could take a screenshot of your settings and tediously re-apply them if you have to.